# Could not find module 'MyCustomFramework' for target 'x86_64-apple-ios-simulator'; found: arm64, armv7-apple-ios, arm64-apple-ios, arm, armv7

Tags: ios, swift, ios-frameworks, xcode11

I have a custom framework that I am archiving for use in another project. After updating to Xcode11 I get the following error in my project utilizing the framework.

Could not find module 'MyCustomFramework' for target 'x86_64-apple-ios-simulator'; found: arm64, armv7-apple-ios, arm64-apple-ios, arm, armv7

My framework works fine on Xcode10 but does not on 11. My target is set to NO for build active architectures only. I have the following for Valid Architectures; arm64e, armv7s, armv7, arm64.

## My build script

```
exec > ${PROJECT_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}_archive.log 2>&1

UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-universal

if [ "true" == ${ALREADYINVOKED:-false} ]
then
echo "RECURSION: Detected, stopping"
else
export ALREADYINVOKED="true"

# make sure the output directory exists
mkdir -p "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}"

echo "Building for iPhoneSimulator"
xcodebuild -workspace "${WORKSPACE_PATH}" -scheme "${TARGET_NAME}" -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 11 Pro Max' ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO ARCHS='i386 x86_64' BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" ENABLE_BITCODE=YES OTHER_CFLAGS="-fembed-bitcode" BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE=bitcode clean build

# Step 1. Copy the framework structure (from iphoneos build) to the universal folder
echo "Copying to output folder"
cp -R "${ARCHIVE_PRODUCTS_PATH}${INSTALL_PATH}" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/"

# Step 2. Copy Swift modules from iphonesimulator build (if it exists) to the copied framework directory
SIMULATOR_SWIFT_MODULES_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${TARGET_NAME}.framework/Modules/${TARGET_NAME}.swiftmodule/."
if [ -d "${SIMULATOR_SWIFT_MODULES_DIR}" ]; then
cp -R "${SIMULATOR_SWIFT_MODULES_DIR}" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${TARGET_NAME}.framework/Modules/${TARGET_NAME}.swiftmodule"
fi

# Step 3. Create universal binary file using lipo and place the combined executable in the copied framework directory
echo "Combining executables"
lipo -create -output "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${EXECUTABLE_PATH}" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${EXECUTABLE_PATH}" "${ARCHIVE_PRODUCTS_PATH}${INSTALL_PATH}/${EXECUTABLE_PATH}"

# Step 4. Create universal binaries for embedded frameworks
#for SUB_FRAMEWORK in $( ls "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${TARGET_NAME}.framework/Frameworks" ); do
#BINARY_NAME="${SUB_FRAMEWORK%.*}"
#lipo -create -output "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${TARGET_NAME}.framework/Frameworks/${SUB_FRAMEWORK}/${BINARY_NAME}" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${SUB_FRAMEWORK}/${BINARY_NAME}" "${ARCHIVE_PRODUCTS_PATH}${INSTALL_PATH}/${TARGET_NAME}.framework/Frameworks/${SUB_FRAMEWORK}/${BINARY_NAME}"
#done

# Step 5. Convenience step to copy the framework to the project's directory
ARCHIVE_PATH="${PROJECT_DIR}/Products"
rm -rf "${ARCHIVE_PATH}"
mkdir "${ARCHIVE_PATH}"

echo "Copying to project dir"
yes | cp -Rf "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${FULL_PRODUCT_NAME}" "${ARCHIVE_PATH}"

open "${ARCHIVE_PATH}"

fi
```

Comment: I have added an alternative solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58192079/7536965

Answer (score 3):

This line is incorrect

```
cp -R "${SIMULATOR_SWIFT_MODULES_DIR}" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${TARGET_NAME}.framework/Modules/${TARGET_NAME}.swiftmodule"
```

Should be

```
cp -R "${SIMULATOR_SWIFT_MODULES_DIR}" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${TARGET_NAME}.framework/Modules/"
```

You'll need to check in the target folder

```
"${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${TARGET_NAME}.framework/Modules/"
```

If there are files like

```
x86_64-apple-ios-simulator.swiftdoc
x86_64-apple-ios-simulator.swiftmodule
x86_64.swiftdoc
x86_64.swiftmodule
```

Before Xcode 11, Apple seems neglect those files so your script works well.

From Xcode 11 those files are seem to be checked rigorously.

Comment: I have checked "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${TARGET_NAME}.framework/Modules/" and those files are not present so there is nothing to copy over to final destination.

Comment: then you'll need to check the source folder ${SIMULATOR_SWIFT_MODULES_DIR} to see if those files are correctly generated. If not then you would need to check if the xcodebuild command line works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5.0-5.1, Xcode 11 
Open Xcode, <your project>, Build Settings, Build Active Architecture Only and change to <NO> for Debug and Release. Architectures set/leave in Standard Architecture -$(ARCHS_STANDART), important is next step:
Valid Architecture: armv7, armv7s, amr64, amr64e, ADD here x86_64 and if you need add i386 for Debug and Release. (String: armv7, armv7s, amr64, amr64e, x86_64)

Choose any simulator in your simulator list and BUILT IT. DONE.

I hope it is works for you.

Description of Architecture:

armv64: iPhoneX, iPhone 5s-8, iPad Air — iPad Pro

armv7 : iPhone3Gs-5c, iPad WIFI(4th gen)

armv6 : iPhone — iPhone3G

-the above if for real devices

i386 : 32-bit simulator

x86_64 : 64-bit simulator