# Xcode 12 - No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=x86_64, VALID_ARCHS=arm64e armv7s arm64 arm7)

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, ios14, xcode12

Since I update Xcode to Xcode 12, I've got this error when I build :

```
Check dependencies
No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=x86_64, VALID_ARCHS=arm64e armv7s arm64 arm7)
```

I try a lot of things :

- Uninstall/reinstall Pods via `pod install`
- `Build Active Architecture Only` to **No** or to **Yes** for *Debug* and *Release*
- Same thing for Pods project

Don't know what to do. This error come when I want to launch on iOS 14, but in iOS 13.7 this work perfectly without change.

**-- EDIT --**

I solve my problem by adding `arm64 arm64e armv7 armv7s x86_64` to `VALID_ARCHS`, both in 'MyProject' and 'MyProjectTest', and it work now.

Comment: try to run on actual device, this issue is on simulator

Comment: @MZubairShamshad Ok I will test that, but how make it work on simulator ? I've not all Apple devices for real ^^

Comment: what is your excluded architectures? arm64? or x86_64?

Comment: This solution works fine
[Use Xcode with Rosetta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68129533/1686454)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If you can't see "VALID_ARCHS" in BuildSettings.
You can click the plus button.

[image]

click "Add User-Defined Setting"

[image]

Input setting name "VALID_ARCHS" , input value "arm64 arm64e armv7 armv7s x86_64"

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer, but I doesn't work anymore... I precise it works since the beginning in a real device. The only problem is for emulator.

Comment: I finally solved the problem. I do exactly what you do, but for "MyProjectTest" to and now, it work !

Comment: @Gargantua i also have this issue. i tried the same but still i am not able to run my app on simulators. Please help

Comment: As I say, I only add what @ShaoJen Chen tell and it work ! I had those lines on"MyProject3" and "MyProject3Tests"

Comment: I added the VALID_ARCHS in all(project,target,AppTest), but no luck for iOS simulator.  it worked only for the device.  Any help?

Comment: I have this issue only on M1 MacbookAir, not on my iMac.

Comment: @NonUmemoto same for me in my M1. I have this issue because I'm trying to solve other problem, but int he thread they suggest to use Build legacy, and when I tried to use that, I get this.

Answer (score 9):

Theorectically it should be enough changing debug from yes to no.

[image]

But as you said it did not work it must be that you have to set `VALID_ARCHS` to what you have plus `x86_64`.

Comment: I also try to put Debug to "No", but I haven't "VALID_ARCHS" in XCode, I don't found it

Comment: @Gargantua Pay attention on the top if it is showing all options or only the basic ones.

Comment: It's the case, "All" is selected

Comment: I have followed your steps and added `x86_64` in `VALID_ARCHS` but no use. How to resolve in Xcode 12.2....

Answer (score 8):

M1 Mac: run Xcode in rosetta(by going to the .app file and clicking "get info" the click "open using rosetta"

Comment: How to run the app in rosetta

Comment: @sejn You need to first have a M1 or M2 Mac to select that option as per the given answer. If you run Xcode in Rosetta, then the binaries will be running under 'Intel'. You can check by opening Activity Monitor, under the `Kind` column, see if it says `Apple` or `Intel`.

Comment: Lol, this just helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Go to your App's target and select 64 bit standard architectures in Architectures section. See attached screenshot

[image]

Comment: I haven't this choice to select, what does I need to do to add this ?

Comment: Add "$(ARCHS_STANDARD_64_BIT)" this in other option in Architectures

Comment: Did you clean build?

Comment: what was your previous value for architectures?

Comment: Standard architectures - $(ARCHS_STANDARD)

Answer (score 3):

run Xcode in rosetta(by going to the .app file and clicking "get info" the click "run under rosetta"

Comment: how to achieve it, can add some screen shots.

Answer (score 2):

For anybody coming across this in 2023:

Apple updated Xcode with 14.3 and moved the Rosetta settings to a per-project option:

https://sarunw.com/posts/open-using-rosetta-in-xcode-14-3/

Answer (score -1):

With Mac M1: Right click into xcode => Get Info => Open using Rosetta
[image]
[image]

Answer (score -2):

In Xcode 12, M1 chip macbook
I just need to run the app in real device that's it