# Xcode 12 Problems: "Build input file cannot be found "- Building for release on a react native app

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, xcode12

When I try to do an archive build for "any iOS device", I receive this error:

> Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[app]-czrkuohjfzuzxxfobfoyptxhyoyo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/[app]/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/[Product Name].app/[Product Name]'

I received this same error when building for an iOS simulator, but this post fixed it - [Problems after upgrading to Xcode 12:ld: building for iOS Simulator, but linking in dylib built for iOS, architecture arm64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63993084/problems-after-upgrading-to-xcode-12ld-building-for-ios-simulator-but-linking).

I am also receiving a warning concerning the architectures that may or may not be relatable to the error:

> None of the architectures in ARCHS (arm64) are valid. Consider setting ARCHS to $(ARCHS_STANDARD) or updating it to include at least one value from VALID_ARCHS (arm64, armv7s, armv7) which is not in EXCLUDED_ARCHS (arm64).

[image: architectures]

[image: VALID_ARCHS]

Comment: Same error here, Xcode update it's being a nightmare...

Comment: Any workarounds

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Build for "Any iOS Device" (for example, "Archive" because you want to upload to AppStore):

- Delete arm64 from "Excluded Architectures"
- Delete x86_64 from VALID_ARCHS
- Add arm64 to VALID_ARCHS

All this changes on both "Build Settings", project and target. And if you want to build for simulator do the inverse path:

- Add arm64 to "Excluded Architectures"
- Delete arm64 from VALID_ARCHS
- Add x86_64 to VALID_ARCHS

That works for me.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much.  Under "Excluded Architectures", I added under release "Any iOS SDK" and removed arm64. Did the same for VALID_ARCHS. I'm a little annoyed still lol.... must be from the battle scars of xcode 12.

Comment: @deimain86 why the is so ....and what particular changes do I need to do when making build...i.e deploying to the appstore

Comment: @AshishGupta Delete arm64 from "Excluded Architectures"
Delete x86_64 from VALID_ARCHS
Add arm64 to VALID_ARCHS

Comment: @deimain86 thanks ...but its already 8 months since i asked the question :)

Comment: I do not have Xcode 12 but I am facing the same issue. I have Xcode 11.7 but I got this project from someone who must be having Xcode 12. Is there any solution for me to make it run?

Comment: Where does one find VALID_ARCHS in Xcode 13?

Comment: @craigpatik see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64051811/17927980)

Answer (score 9):

So I had the exact same issue. After updating to Xcode 12 I had originally set both my **project** and **target** 's 'Excluded Architecture' to arm64 in order to run on Simulator. But, as you mention, that blocks anything from working on Release / Real device. All I had to do was switch to 'Any iOS Simulator SDK = arm64' instead of all of them, see screen shot below:

[link to screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwSWm.png)

Answer (score 2):

I know this question has been answered but this piece of information may help someone: This kind of error may also be produced if you have no node_modules folder e.g. you have deleted it and forgot to re-create it

Comment: I re-create it, but facing the same issue, I don't have Xcode 12 i have 11.7, So I don't see `Excluded Architectures`,Do u have any idea?

Comment: No, sorry, I don't

Comment: I also have Xcode 11.7 but I got this project from someone who must be having Xcode 12. Is there any solution for me? How can I make it run? @OliverD or Martin

Answer (score 2):

This error started happening for me with a SwiftUI app. I didn't need the file for my project, but the settings were set to generate a file anyways. What worked for me was to go into Project Navigator --> App Target --> Build Settings --> Packaging and delete the value (file name) for the *`Info.plist File`* key.

Answer (score -1):

This problem wasted a lot of my time after upgrading to xcode 12, using React Native 0.63. Excluding architectures did not work for me.

Symptoms: "build input file could not be found..." when running on device in debug AND release. Simulator worked fine.

To Fix: Editor > Validate Settings... > Perform Changes

Now my app builds fine on device.

Comment: Dang. That didn't work for me. Getting same error. :(