# Error: Build Input file not found, when tried to run the app on iOS simulator

Tags: ios, xcode12

After upgrading the Xcode to 12.2 from 11.x , I'm getting a wierd error when trying to run the app on iOS Simulator.

The error is:

```
error: Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/mrt/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxx-fqqnstjlfcnipqbcjbnhysubdksn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/xxx.app/xxx' (in target 'xxx' from project 'xxx')
```

- Here the missing /xxx is the unix executable file inside the .app folder.

When I try to build it on phone, there is no such error.

When I checked the location in finder, the unix executable file inside the .app is missing, for Debug-iphonesimulator, but it is present in Debug-iphoneos

I have no idea, why that executable file is missing.

- I have added the arm64 in the excluded arch section in the new Xcode. Both in project and target Buil Settings.

[image]

- I tried changing project settings to Legacy Build, and it resulted in same error.
- I haven't moved any plist files or any files in my project. I deleted some unused targets and related files. The error didnot mention anything about deleted files. Hence I do not think , those could be the reason. I tried this SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52435202/build-input-file-cannot-be-found-swift-4-2-xcode-10-0), and it didnt solve my issue. My plist file path is `$(SRCROOT)/xxx/SupportingFiles/xxx.plist`
- I did delete derived data and clean, many times. Not solved.
- I tried adding x86_64 under VALID_ARCHS and adding arm64 under exluded arch settings, as suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64123206/xcode-12-problems-build-input-file-cannot-be-found-building-for-release-on). Not solved.

Is there anything that I'm missing ?

Answer (score 1):

THIS error maybe your update Xcode version like: Xcode 10 to Xcode 12, the your old PROJECTS will got this error, can't running your app again.

Try this:

1:
VALID_ARCHS (in the "Architectures" tab) key on the BuildSettings of "PROJECT" GROUP
or just search "VALID_ARCHS", maybe in the other Tabs( or in the "User-Defined")

set value "arm64" or others

IMG SIMPLE: [image]

2:
select TARGETS: your app's target

search for the same KEY ("VALID_ARCHS") and just selection the current row and click "delete" on your keyboard, there will be with default values(it is the same value of PROJECT's Build Settings )

3: clear and rebuild