# Could not find module 'XXXX' for target 'x86_64-apple-ios-simulator'; found: arm64, arm64-apple-ios-simulator in Swift Project?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

This error has been stopping me progress with my project for a while now and nothing seems to be working for me.

I have added A pod to my swift project but when I try to import it into my app, I get this error:

```
Could not find module 'ImagePicker' for target 'x86_64-apple-ios-simulator'; found: arm64, arm64-apple-ios-simulator
```

I've searched far and wide and tried almost all the solutions and still nothing seems to be working.

I'm using the latest Xcode.

is there anything I need to do fix this as this is stopping me from building the app.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/56959002/7241429

Comment: @abdurrehman, I already have. didn't work.

Answer (score 8):

I have the same issue on the M1 laptop.
Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66420027/9682889) solution:

```
post_install do |installer_representation|
    installer_representation.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH'] = 'NO'
            config.build_settings['BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION'] = 'YES'
        end
    end
end
```

Alternatively, you can change default scheme to Release, instead of Debug, by going to the top menu `Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme`, select your Run scheme as Release.

However, better solution would be to simply make sure you're running Xcode using Rosetta. Simple do the `Get Info` on the Xcode icon, from there in popup window make sure that `Open using Rosetta` is checked

Answer (score 5):

I'm using SPM for dependency management and ran into issues with my M1 laptop.
I had Excluded architectures within the top level project build settings set to arm64, which is where I ran into the problem
[image: excluded architectures]

After I removed that it worked.

Here's a screenshot of the Architectures section in the Project build settings, after making the change (ignore dark mode look, I was switching laptops).
[image: Project build settings]