# SwiftUI Package dependencies isn't working in real iOS device

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, package

I've implemented packages in SwiftUI using **Add Package** These packages are working fine in the simulator. But when I've tried to run on a real iOS device (iPhone 8 plus). It is showing the error. I've deleted **Derived data** and **Clean Build Folder** and **Build**. Even I've restarted Xcode, removed packages, and again re-added then also it's not working on real deivce.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried if there is any architecture issue? VALID_ARCHS
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68778205/7024806

Comment: @WasiSadman I've tried. But still, it's not working on the real device.