# could not find module 'Alamofire' for target 'x86_64-apple-ios-simulator'

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I install alamofire via Carthage and get this error:

could not find module 'Alamofire' for target 'x86_64-apple-ios-simulator'; found: armv7-apple-ios, arm64-apple-ios,
at: /Users/datdinh/Desktop/a/requestTest/Carthage/Build/iOS/Alamofire.framework/Modules/Alamofire.swiftmodule

Comment: Are you using M1 chip ?

Comment: i use AMD chip, and i use macos on vmware https://imgur.com/a/pJQcrdO

Comment: check this answers : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56957632/could-not-find-module-for-target-x86-64-apple-ios-simulator

Comment: I have a similar problem. Did you find any silver bullet solution?

Answer (score 5):

I recently had the exact same problem, with Xcode 14.1 and a Scheme/Configuration called "Debug".

After a day and tweaking, **I found out its only related to Xcodes `Configuration` & `Scheme` name, as soon as I changed it from `Debug` to `Test` or anything else, the problem disappeared, correctly building necessary architure for the Simulator.**

Note: I did have another Configuration/Scheme with debug-like settings which worked flawless, so I knew that in general my Xcode `Build Settings` were alright.

Besides that, Xcode 14 is quite buggy, for me not displaying compile errors for currently open files. Since I am on Ventura I cannot use Xcode 13.4.1. A Nightmare!

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me with M2 pro chip and Xcode 14.2

Answer (score 2):

I have **Xcode 14.2** and multiple `Schemes` in the app like `MyApp2-debug` and `MyApp2-release`
I resolved the same problem by changing the `Scheme` of `Debug` to `MyApp-debug` and `Release` to `MyApp-release` or anything else.
Other `Schemes` were working fine.