# Compile error on M1 for Sim Without Rosetta

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild, swift-package-manager

**Error**

> Could not find module 'Cartography' for target 'x86_64-apple-ios-simulator': found: arm64_ios_simulator...

**Setup** is simple:

- A framework (embedded Xcode project) that has a Swift Package dependency on Cartography (or any package, really)
- An app that uses that framework
- Ensure that the Framework has a `import` statement for the Swift Package, and that the App has an `import` statement for the framework.
- Try to compile for any iPhone or iPad simulator

**Note**: Using Rosetta to run on simulator works, but **I need a solution that works without Rosetta.**

Comment: Isn't this really just a variety of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56957632/could-not-find-module-for-target-x86-64-apple-ios-simulator ?

Comment: @matt looks good, I've voted to close as a dupe of that question. Thanks and good to see you.

Comment: @matt not sure that losing the context here is a good idea. It's likely the same problem, but might not be.

Comment: I think the point is that a framework is already set in stone by the time it reaches you. If the framework wasn't built with a slice for M1, it needs to be rebuilt.

Comment: Thanks @matt that's quite helpful. I didn't realize that the frameworks are coming down fully-formed. I'll read up on a bit on SPM. 

On the other hand, I have to switch Rosetta off to run on mac-as-ipad (profile issues) and then turn it back on to run on iOS simulator (missing slices). I'm guessing these are normal problems.