Could not find module for target 'arm64-apple-ios-simulator'; found: x86_64-apple-ios-simulator
Recently my iOS Unit tests stopped working and I have no clue, what is going on.
Current Xcode Version: Version 15.4 (15F31d)
Simulator: iPhone 17.0.1
The unit tests always stop at
@testable import MyApp

with the error:

Could not find module 'MyApp' for target 'arm64-apple-ios-simulator'; found: x86_64-apple-ios-simulator

Following settings are getting set in the Pods file:
config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '5.0'
config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.0'
config.build_settings['APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY'] = 'NO'
config.build_settings['EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] = "arm64"
config.build_settings['ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH'] = 'NO'
config.build_settings['BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION'] = 'YES'
config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
config.build_settings['DEVELOPMENT_TEAM'] = '62365DL5L2'
config.build_settings['CLANG_WARN_STRICT_PROTOTYPES'] = 'NO'

I tried changing my Cocoa Pods script to
config.build_settings['ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH'] = "YES" // this was "NO" before

but it did not solve the problem. Neither did setting Build active Architecture only to YES
nor removing this line in the pods file fixed this issue:
config.build_settings['EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] = "arm64"


Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/66420027/833395

Unfortunately did not work. I added my pod script
